# how to generate the pdf when the form is submitting in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, css, html, pdf-generation, laravel-5

I am working on a  product management system and there is a module called purchase.

I have wrote the `store()` method the controller and the model part too.

Now I want to generate the invoice when I click on submit button. I used PDF generator plugin as `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`. I'm new to PHP & Laravel and just wants to know instructions to do the PDF generation process.

Comment: there is everything in document you just need to follow it https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Answer (score 1):

You would follow the install steps for Laravel 5:

1. Add this, `Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,` to your `config/app.php` file as a ServiceProvider
2. Add this, `'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,` to your facades in your `config/app.php` file

And then in your store method, after you save all the information, you could generate a PDF like so:

```
$pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdf.invoice', $data);
return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

This would load the `invoice` view stored in `resources/views/pdf` with the values stored in `$data`, and then return a downloadable file called `invoice.pdf`.

This all comes directly from the **Using** section of the DomPDF [docs](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf#using).

Comment: I understood what you told but im confused with this $data.  Can you show me how to indicate this . I have no idea where to put $data is it like $data= array ( 'test'=>$request->get ('test_name'),........ .........);  and then "the code you given "

Comment: @sandunijayawardena you use it similarly to how you use `Mail` if you've ever used that before. `$data` is an an array with keys and values that you pass in and can use. For example `$data['name'] = "name";` would allow you to use `$name` inside your view.

Answer (score 0):

**1-** Install the DOMPDF according to this [Github Link](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)

**2-** Form page

```
 <form id="FOO" method="POST" action="/pdf">

     <input type="text" name="object" >
     <button type="submit">Generate</button>

 </form>
```

**3-** Route :`Route::post('pdf' , 'EventsController@PDFGenerator');`

Please notice,here,that you will either need to include a hidden input,with csrf token,or simply exclude this route in the `VerifyCSRFToken.php`  middleware,otherwise it will not let you post(if you haven't worked with Auth yet,don't mind this notice)

**4-** Controller page now

```
public function PDFGenerator (Request $request){
    $html = <<<ENDHTML

   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>Foo</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 30px;">

      <center style="text-decoration: underline;">{$request->object}</center>

    </body>
   </html>
ENDHTML;
    $dompdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $dompdf->loadHTML($html);
    $dompdf->stream("hello.pdf");
    return $dompdf->stream();

}
```

[This is the Heredoc documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) in case you needed more information about how to use it.

Don't forget to include the library in your controller,waiting for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 :

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

Step 2. Update config/app.php
Open `config/app.php` file. Add the following line to ‘providers’ array:

```
'providers' => [
....
 Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
],


'aliases' => [
....
 'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
]
```

Step 3. Add routes
Now open your web.php file and add following route.

```
<?php


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
  
use App\Http\Controllers\PDFController;
  
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
  
Route::get('generate-pdf','PDFController@generatePDF');
```

Step 4. Add Link In Blade File

```
<a href="route('generate-pdf')">Generate PDF</a>
```

Step 5. Create Controller
Add your controller below code.

```
<?PHP
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PDF;
  
class PDFController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function generatePDF()
{
    $data = [
      'title' => 'First PDF ',
      'heading' => 'Hello Bro',
      'content' => 'Data content'        
        ];
    
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('generate_pdf', $data);

    return $pdf->download('Laravel.pdf');
  }
 }
```

Step 6. Create Blade File
Let’s create `generate_pdf.blade.php` for layout of pdf file and put
following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Generate Pdf</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>{{ $heading}}</h1>
  <div>
     <p>{{$content}}</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```